# Pandas read_sql in chunksize bug/issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading data from Mysql and MSsql databases using pandas read_sql and do some processing over chunks and finally save to destination mongodb, The problem I am facing is as soon as the number of chunks gets completed the code slips in to an infinite loop of chunk processing and keep repeating the second/third last record of the last chunk? Any ideas why this is happening, have any of you ever experienced this issues/bug! In the snippet below you can see what I am doing with chunk processing! do you think it is a Python/Pandas issue or Database issue?
Pandas version: 1.1.5 and Python: 3.6.10

```
chunks = pd.read_sql_query(query, src_db, chunksize=50000)
i = 0
for chunk in tqdm(chunks):
    try:
        """
        I do some processes here to chunks, like adding columns and removing columns
        and then save to destination mongodb
        """
        dest_db.insert_many(chunk.to_dict("records"))
        i += 1
        print("chunk number: " + str(i) )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: It could be because of tqdm. Did you try without tqdm?

Comment: No, let me try but does tqdm effects this, also if the processing I am doing takes a little longer does it effects the state of generator object?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it shall not effect the state of generator object. This is something I've a while ago moving data from mssql to postgresql https://dev.to/abbazs/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-postgresql-database-1a1b